# How to calculate the number of occurrences of individual HTML tags in ? (Java)

Tags: java, html, count, tags

I have below string, it is body of HTTP response, and I need to calculate the number of occurrences of individual HTML tags and sort them by number of instances using Java.

```
 "<div><p><span class="lede">Today, the European </span>Space Agency&apos;s Rosetta spacecraft will engage its thrusters for one final maneuver: a suicidal plunge toward the comet it has been orbiting for two years and chasing for a decade. After Rosetta collides with comet 67P/Churyumov-Gerasimenko....."
```

Please somebody help
Thank in advance

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why  it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time  to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a library like [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/overview-summary.html) to get all of the documents elements and manipulate them as needed.

You could create a `HashMap<String, Long>` for each tag and the number of occurrences. Then you could iterate all elements of a JSoup `Document` recursively, updating the map at each pass, and last, sort the `HashMap`.

Don't forget to escape quotes with a backslash. `String html = "<div class=\"like-this\">div content</div>";`

For example (not tested) something like

```
Map<String, Long> counts = new HashMap<>();
String html = " your html string goes here ";    

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elements = document.body().select("*");
recursiveWalk(elements, counts);

// your map here, sort it

// method to walk the document
private void recursiveWalk(List<Element> elements, Map<String, Long> counts) {
    for (Element el : elements) {
        String tag = el.tagName();
        long number = counts.getOrDefault(tag, 0L) + 1;
        counts.put(tag, number);
        recursiveWalk(elements.children(), counts);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me but when the content of the document has words such as "body", "div" it also counts them as tags while they are just a part of sentence.